# Jquery not working dreamweaver. Not sure if properly linked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So this is a weird problem. I have a very simple Jquery code in JavaScript file and a very basic HTML file in dreamweaver. I have linked the .js with html as usual but nothing is taking any effect at all both in dreamweaver and in browser as well.

HTML Code for HEAD

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>College ink.</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="homeCSS.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery-Home.js"></script>

</head>
```

HTML CODE FOR SPECIFIC ELEMENT IN BODY

```
<section>
    <div class="mainBox" id="designBox">    
    <div class="mainSubBox">
        <p class="subBoxText">
            <a href="uploadPage.html">Design</a>
         </p>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

THIS IS THE JQUERY CODE (There is nothing above or below this code in .js file)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mainBox').mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

Can you find out the actual problem? Has it got anything to with CSS?
Thank You

Comment: It seems that you didn't include jquery library?

Comment: what is `JQuery-Home.js`?

Comment: Dev Tools is your friend!

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I think thats jQuery he renamed it

Comment: @FaizAhmed, actually, i think that content of that file is posted here.

Comment: JQuery-Home.js is the name of javascript file. Easier to understand this way. @ClaudioRedi

Comment: JQuery-Home.js is the name of your JavaScript file, or jQuery??

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you included the jQuery library. Add:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

in the head beside your other script.

Comment: + add http: if you test locally (like OP probably do). :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery install link:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add this above where your javascript file is linked in the document.